# .NET Optimization of F# Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: .net, optimization, f#, sieve-of-eratosthenes, f#-interactive

I am fiddling with F# and using the FSI REPL I noticed that there was a huge efficiency discrepancy between two slightly different implementations of my beginner's naive Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation. The first with an extra if:

```
let rec sieve max current pList =
    match current with
    | 2 -> sieve max (current + 1) (current::pList)
    | 3 -> sieve max (current + 2) (current::pList)
    | n when n < max ->
        if (n % 5 = 0) || (n % 3 = 0) then
            sieve max (current + 2) (current::pList)
        else if (pList |> (List.map (fun n -> current % n = 0)) |> List.contains true) then
            sieve max (current + 2) (pList)
        else
            sieve max (current + 2) (current::pList)
    | n when n >= max
        -> pList
    | _
        ->  printfn "Error: list length: %A, current: %A" (List.length pList) current
            [-1]
```

and the second without:

```
let rec sieve max current pList =
    match current with
    | 2 -> sieve max (current + 1) (current::pList)
    | 3 -> sieve max (current + 2) (current::pList)
    | n when n < max ->
        if (pList |> (List.map (fun n -> current % n = 0)) |> List.contains true) then
            sieve max (current + 2) (pList)
        else
            sieve max (current + 2) (current::pList)
    | n when n >= max
        -> pList
    | _
        ->  printfn "Error: list length: %A, current: %A" (List.length pList) current
            [-1]
```

The one with the extra `if` branch is actually *slower* despite the fact it should seem it would be faster.
I then timed both implementations in the REPL using the following:

`#time`

`sieve 200000 2 []`

`#time`

and saw that on my machine, the implementation with the extra `if` statement took around 2 minutes while the one without took around 1 minute each time it was run.
How is this possible? By adding an `if` statement which takes care of multiples of 3 or 5, it actually is slower than only mapping over the entire list and then finding if there are any divisors of a number in the list of primes.
*How?* Is it just that F# is THAT optimized for dealing with lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra if in the first sieve, presumably intended to be a shortcut, actually changes the behaviour a bit. Instead of removing everything divided by 3 and 5 it actually adds it. It is easy to see if you compare the output:

```
1st sieve: [19; 17; 15; 13; 11; 9; 7; 5; 3; 2]
2st sieve: [19; 17; 13; 11; 7; 5; 3; 2]
```

I assume that you want is something like this:

```
if (n % 5 = 0) || (n % 3 = 0) then
    sieve max (current + 2) (pList)
```

However, in this case it will not include 5 (obviously). So the correct code is

```
if (n <> 5 && n % 5 = 0) || (n <> 3 && n % 3 = 0) then
    sieve max (current + 2) (pList)
```

Check the performance of the code above - should be fine.

Comment: Ah. So the real bug was my lack of code revision :)

Answer (score 2):

The extra `if` performs the extra computation, but doesn't break the execution flow, which happily continues on to the second `if`. So in effect, you have only added some useless computation to your function. No wonder it takes longer now!

You must be thinking of something like this:

```
if (a)
    return b;
if (x)
    return y;
else 
    return z;
```

Well, this won't work in F# the same way it works in C# or Java or whatever you're thinking in terms of. F# doesn't have "early return". There are no "statements", everything is an expression, everything has a result.

Adding such useless computation will actually generate a warning. If you pay attention to the warnings, you should notice one saying "*this value is being discarded*" or some such. The compiler is trying to help you out by pointing at a useless function call.

To fix this, replace the second `if` with `elif`:

```
if (n % 5 = 0) || (n % 3 = 0) then
    sieve max (current + 2) (current::pList)
elif (pList |> (List.map (fun n -> current % n = 0)) |> List.contains true) then
    sieve max (current + 2) (pList)
else
    sieve max (current + 2) (current::pList)
```

This will make the second branch only execute when the first one fails.

P.S. Come to think of it, such an `if` without an `else` shouldn't even compile, because its result type cannot be determined. I'm not sure what's going on there.

P.P.S. `List.map f |> List.contains true` is better expressed as `List.exists f`. Both shorter *and* more performant.

Comment: Actually that was a copy and paste error.
I corrected to show both versions.

Comment: Oh, well... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, lists are not necessarily efficient. I once created a function to create an array of booleans where every prime number is true, and every non-prime is false:

```
let sieveArray limit =
    let a = Array.create limit true
    let rec setArray l h s x =
        if l <= h then
            a.[l] <- x
            setArray (l + s) h s x
    a.[0] <- false; a.[1] <- false
    for i = 0 to a.Length - 1 do
        if a.[i]
        then setArray (i + i) (a.Length - 1) i false
    a
```

To get a list of the actual primes, you can just map the indices, filter the resulting array:

```
sieveArray limit
|> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i, x)
|> Seq.filter snd
|> Seq.map fst
|> Seq.toList
```